# How to run multiple JAR files at differnt locations from a command prompt

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

I have 2 jar files at different locations. I need to run both these jar files from a single command prompt window.

I referred to many SO links and google links and created this batch job.

```
START SET JPOS_DIR=D:\Installable\JPOS\Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11
cd /D %JPOS_DIR%
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain

START SET JPOS_DIR=D:\Installable\JPOS_Instance-2\Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11
cd /D %JPOS_DIR%
start "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```

But i am getting the below error message

**"Windows cannot find -cp. make sure you type the name correctly and try again."**

Can someone tell me what I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for the [start command](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) is as follows,

```
START "title" [/D path] [options] "command" [parameters]
```

so in the command,

```
start "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```

it considers "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" as title and -cp as the command to run, thats why you get the error.

Try using the following command,

```
start "title" "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```

Alternatively, you can run without any quotes where we don't need to pass the title,

```
start java -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```

set Java in PATH before executing this command. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Prem, does this help you? please let us know the output with the above suggestions.

Comment: your answer worked for me. I missed the title thing.marked your answer and upvoted. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`-cp` is not valid windows `cdm` command... I think you missed `start` at first execution:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```

must be

```
start "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java" -cp Iso8583jPOSJavaAgent-0.0.11.jar com.hp.sv.iso8583.jpos.ISOForwarderMain
```